# antiderivative of $\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$, complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I have the domain $\mathbb{C} \backslash [0,1]$ and want to show that $$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z(z-1)}dz = 0$$
for all closed curves $\gamma$. I want to accomplish this by explicitly finding an antiderivative.

I did a partial fraction decomposition and got
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z(z-1)} = \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z}$$

Now
$$ F(z) =\text{log}(z-1) - \text{log}(z)$$
would be an antiderivative but I don't feel comfortable with the complex logarithm yet. Is my $F(z)$ well-defined on my whole domain? If not, how do I find a well-defined antiderivative?

Comment: That is at best you can do (but your $F$ is still not defined on the whole domain). You have to use the fact that $\gamma$ does not pass throught $[0,1]$.

Comment: @KajHansen: Unless I am mistaken, the Cauchy-Goursat theorem applies to *simply-connected* domains only. Otherwise you could apply it to $1/z$ on $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$ .

Comment: @MartinR, oops.  You are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression
$$
F(z)=\log(z−1)−\log(z)
$$
is *not* well-defined on your domain, because neither $\log(z−1)$
nor $\log(z)$ are holomorphic in $\mathbb{C} \backslash [0,1]$.
One can probably solve that by choosing the arguments of the
logarithms carefully, but it becomes much easier if the right-hand
side is rewritten as $\log \frac{z-1}{z}$.

The Möbius transformation $T(z) = \dfrac{z-1}{z}$ maps $\mathbb{\hat C} \backslash [0,1]$
conformally onto $\mathbb{C} \backslash (-\infty,0]$, so you can
define
$$
F(z) = \log \frac{z-1}{z}
$$
where 
$$\log w = \log|w| + i \arg w \quad (-\pi < \arg w < \pi)
$$ is a holomorphic branch
of the logarithm on $\mathbb{C} \backslash (-\infty,0]$.

Then $F$ is an "explicit" antiderivate of 
$$
\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z}
$$
This can either be verified directly, or you argue as follows:
In any disc $D \subset \mathbb{C} \backslash [0,1]$
$$
  F(z) = \log(z-1) - \log z + C
$$
for *some* holomorphic branch of $\log(z-1)$ and $ \log z$ in $D$,
and the result follows by differentiation.

Comment: I have tried to answer the question *"I want to accomplish this by explicitly finding an antiderivative."*. Of course there are other and simpler arguments why the integral is zero.

Comment: Thanks, I think this answers my question. Just to curious: how would you do it without the antiderivative? Is there another way besides using the residue theorem (because I don't know this yet)?

Comment: @Marc: I don't know which is the best or appropriate way to do it without residues, sorry. You could substitute $z = 1/t$, then you get an integral of a  holomorphic function in a simply-connected domain.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on this? Transforming the function / domain in such a way that we can apply Cauchy's theorem sounds interesting, but I don't understand it from your brief comment. (Maybe make another answer?)

Answer (score 4):

The solution depends on your closed curve, which poles it does contain in the interior of γ. Since you excluded [0,1] any closed curve will not contain both the poles, or it will contain both and can't have $γ(t)=0$ or $γ(t)=1$. (Curve must have a finite length)

Lets consider:\begin{align}\oint_\gamma f(z)\, dz\end{align} where $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$

[Theorem:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) \begin{align}\oint_\gamma f(z)\, dz =
2\pi i \sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{I}(\gamma, a_k) 
\operatorname{Res}( f, a_k )\end{align}

In this specific case $n=2$ and $a_1=0,a_2=1$

Since a close curve will contain both of them, or none of them, then:

\begin{align}\operatorname{I}(\gamma, a_1)=\operatorname{I}(\gamma, a_2)\end{align}

Therefore: \begin{align}\oint_\gamma f(z)\, dz =
2\pi i  \operatorname{I}(\gamma, a_1) \sum_{k=1}^2  
\operatorname{Res}( f, a_k )\end{align}

Theorem 2: Pole order = 1 $\Rightarrow$ \begin{align}Res(f,z_i) = \lim_{z\to z_i} \frac{z-z_i}{f(z)}\end{align}
At $z=0$,\begin{align}Res(f,0) = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z}{z(z-1)} = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{1}{z-1}=-1\end{align} 
At $z=1$ \begin{align}Res(f,1) = \lim_{z\to 1} \frac{z-1}{z(z-1)}=1 \end{align}

Therefore:

\begin{align}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z(z-1)}dz = 2\pi i  \operatorname{I}(\gamma, a_1) \sum_{k=1}^2  
\operatorname{Res}( f, a_k )=2\pi i  \operatorname{I}(\gamma, a_1) (1-1)=0\end{align}

Comment: Latex is not difficult to learn actually... You can click "edit" in the OP's question and you'll see a lot of code you need.

Comment: And that is the reason you down vote an absolutely correct answer?

Comment: Your answer is correct, but is of very low quality. (Yes I downvoted your answer). Note not only that your picture is a bit hard to see, but also that the information in the picture cannot be searched through the web.

Comment: Don't you have to take the *winding number* into account? How would you show that the winding number of $\gamma$ with respect to $z=0$ is the same as the winding number with respect to $z=1$, so that the residues cancel? (Perhaps I am overlooking something simple.)

Comment: I will fix the answer to account for that and write it in latex.

Comment: But why isn't  $\operatorname{I}(\gamma, 0) = 2$ and $\operatorname{I}(\gamma, 1) = 5$ possible? Don't get me wrong: I know that $\operatorname{I}(\gamma, 0)=\operatorname{I}(\gamma, 1)$ here and that the integral is zero, I am just wondering about the precise reasoning.

Comment: Lets consider a simple γ(t) (Doesn't intersect with it self). Lets also assume the interior contains 1 and not 0 (and doesn't pass through 0 or 1).Then around 0 there is an indefinitely small ball which is not contained in the interior.Also around 1 there is an small ball which is contained in the interior. Connecting 2 points (not all) inside the ball results in intersection with [-ε,0].
Therefore  the boundary γ(t) must pass through (0,1). To generalize this it takes other theorems in mind

Answer (score 1):

Another possible argument (in response to your above comment):
With the substitution
$$
z = \frac 1w \, ,\quad  dz = -\frac{dw}{w^2}
$$ 
you get
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z(z-1)} \,dz = \int_{\gamma'} \frac{-1}{\frac 1w(\frac 1w-1)} \,\frac{dw}{w^2} = \int_{\gamma'} \frac{1}{w-1} \, dw
$$
where $\gamma'$ is a closed curve in $D = \Bbb C \setminus [1, \infty) $.
$D$ is simply-connected and $1/(w-1)$ holomorphic in $D$.
It follows from Cauchy's integral theorem that the integral is zero.

Comment: I won't change the accepted answer because the other one fits my question better, but this is beautiful. Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried to work this out in detail and got the problem that there's no $z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash [0,1]$ such that $w=0$ (we'd have to use $z=\infty$). So it seems to me that we can't include $0$ in the domain after substitution. This would imply the loss of the simply-connected property which is necessary for Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @Marc: I don' think that you actually need the fact that infinity is mapped to zero.  You only need that $\gamma'$ is a closed curve in $D = \Bbb C \setminus [1, \infty) $, $D$ is simply-connected and $1/(w-1)$ holomorphic in $D$. Therefore the integral on the rhs is zero.

Comment: My reasoning is this: if $0$ isn't in $D$, $D$ isn't simply connected. I don't see how $0$ can be in $D$ because no $z \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfies the equation $0 = \frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: $D$ is defined as $D = \Bbb C \setminus [1, \infty)$, not as the image of $\mathbb{C} \backslash [0,1]$ under $1/z$.

Comment: What determines how $D$ is defined? I would say that $D$ is determined by the points on all curves $\gamma'$. But $0$ is not a possible point on any $\gamma'$. $\gamma'$ is derived from $\gamma$ and $0$ on $\gamma'$ doesn't correspond to any complex number on $\gamma$.

Comment: @Marc: No. I have defined $D := \Bbb C \setminus [1, \infty)$. And $\gamma'$ happens to be a curve in $D$, that's all. - Or, put in another way: $\int_{\gamma'} \frac{1}{w-1} \, dw = 0 $ for *all* closed curves in $D$, *in particular* for those which are the image of  a $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C} \backslash [0,1]$ under $z \to 1/z$ .

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I'm still not completely comfortable with the situation, but I cannot pinpoint my remaining issues. Thanks again for your help!